# Apostol: Why exactly is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}$ not defined at origin if the partial derivative of $\sqrt{|xy|}$ exists at origin?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the scalar field $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$.

Here is a $3D$ plot

[image]

In Apostol's *Calculus* we are asked to verify that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are zero at the origin.

I know how to show this by using the definition of partial derivatives. For example

$$\frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial x}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(\langle 0,0\rangle+h\langle 1,0\rangle)-f(0,0)}{h}\tag{1}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\tag{2}$$

$$=0$$

But my question regards the expression

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}\tag{3}$$

which is the partial derivative when $x>0$ and $y>0$ (alternatively, when both are negative).

What are the precise reasons that this expression isn't true at the origin, and yet the partial derivative is defined at the origin?

Note that this expression isn't defined at the origin. But why?

It is defined for all points except the origin on the line of points of form $(x,0)$.

To obtain (3), we took the limit of

$$\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\tag{4}$$

and the resulting expression isn't defined at the origin.

On the other hand to show that the partial derivative does exist at the origin we took the limit of

$$\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\tag{5}$$

It is not clear to me why the limit of this expression is defined, but the limit of (4) evaluated at the origin isn't defined.

Comment: At the origin it is not even wrong: it makes no sense. Neither does the other expression you just added.

Comment: I had an incorrect expression for the partial derivative, is this why you say it makes no sense? It is corrected now.

Comment: You rightly also just added "First of all, it isn't defined at the origin." This answers "What are the precise reasons that this expression isn't true at the origin?". I do not see any other question in your post, so imo: end of the story.

Comment: I think I am pondering why the expression $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}$ exists on the entire line of points $(x,0)$ but not at $(0,0)$. After all, the expression came from a limit that has the same form as the limit I used to show that the partial derivative does in fact exist at $(0,0)$. Maybe its just an algebra thing.

Comment: (2) is not correct: the result of limit evaluation of partial derivative at (0,0) is undetermined, while you found it to be zero. (3) also comfirms the $\frac 00$.

Comment: @WindSoul (1) and (2) are correct, directly from the definition of partial derivative. It doesn't matter that the general formula for the partial derivative valid at different points doesn't converge to that value.

Comment: @aschepler, At $x=0$ $g(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ is not differentiable, therefore $\sqrt{|y|}\cdot g(x)$ is not differentiable.

The confusion came from multiplying $\sqrt{|0|}=0$ with a number that doesn’t exist in the real set (the derivative of g at zero) and obtaining the zero as result.

Comment: @WindSoul $f$ is not differentiable at the origin, true. But the partial derivatives do exist there, and both equal zero.

Comment: @aschepler, there is no partial derivative at (0,0) because $[f_x(x,y)]_{(0,0)}=[\sqrt{|y|}\cdot \underbrace{g\prime(x)}_{\text{NOT A NUMBER!!!}}]_{(0,0)}$. You can’t multiply zero with a number that doesn’t exist to obtain a real number in result.

Comment: @WindSoul No. What definition of $f_x$ gives you that formula?

Comment: @aschepler, in the limit definition used by OP- the Leibniz notation, $f(h,0)$ is evaluated at zero thus the limit is rendered zero. This I find incorrect because the result is zero only when you multiplied zero with a real number. In this case $\sqrt{|0|}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{|h|}}{h}\to 0\cdot \pm \infty=\text{indeterminate}$. The OP evaluation of the limit to zero is inconsistent with my finding that the limit does not exist. If I made a mistake I don’t see where.

Comment: @WindSoul That is a correct definition (among several equivalent ways of stating it). You do substitute the one coordinate before taking the limit along the other. Quote any definition of partial derivative you find, and it will say the partial derivative exists.

Answer (score 1):

Turning it around, another interesting question is "why do the partial derivatives exist at the origin even though the function is not differentiable?"

Just like a simple function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable if the function's graph near the point is similar to a line which is not vertical, a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is called differentiable if the function acts similar to a function linear in each input coordinate. For $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, this means the graph near the point is similar to a plane which is not vertical.

A differentiable function has the nice property that we can know the approximate rate of change along any path through the domain from just a gradient vector. One definition of "differentiable" here is:

> A real-valued function $f$ whose domain $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at a point $\vec r$ in the interior of $D$ if there is a vector $\vec u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that for every path $\sigma : \{t \in \mathbb{R} \mid -1 < t < 1\} \to D$ with $\sigma(0)=\vec r$ and $\sigma$ differentiable at $0$,
>
> $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(\sigma(t)) - f(\vec r)}{t} = \vec u \cdot \sigma'(0) \label{eq:1} \tag{1} $$
>
> If this vector $\vec u$ exists, it is unique and is the gradient of $f$ at $\vec r$: $\vec u = \nabla f(\vec r)$.

(More generally, a function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ has similar properties using the Jacobian matrix in place of the gradient vector.)

We also have the simple gradient formula like

$$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \hat \imath + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \hat \jmath \label{eq:2} \tag{2}$$

The essential relation between equations $\ref{eq:1}$ and $\ref{eq:2}$ is that the partial derivatives are determined from the two simplest paths $\sigma$: $\sigma(t) = (t,0)$ or $\sigma(t) = (0,t)$. So IF $f$ is differentiable, then the partial derivatives do exist, and $\ref{eq:2}$ gives us an easy way to compute $\nabla f$, and then we can use it more generally along any path via $\ref{eq:1}$. But just the existence of partial derivatives doesn't prove the function is differentiable at that point, since they only capture behavior on those two paths, not along all paths. And other theorems which involve partial derivatives, or the gradient or Jacobian almost always require differentiability.

When $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$, this example function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$ is differentiable and has gradient

$$ \nabla f = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{|xy|} \left(\frac{\hat \imath}{x} + \frac{\hat \jmath}{y}\right) \tag{3}$$

When $x=0$ or $y=0$, the example function is not differentiable. If $y=0$ and $x \neq 0$, then even though $f$ is not differentiable, it does have the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ since the particular path along the $x$-axis stays exactly in the groove where $f=0$. But along most other paths we're likely to try, the rate of change of $f$ approaches an infinity. The same way, if $x=0$ and $y \neq 0$, $f$ is not differentiable but has $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$. And at the origin point itself, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, but $f$ is still not differentiable because on other paths approaching the origin $f$ changes too fast.

Comment: Your convention here is far from universal. I say that I can write down the Jacobian matrix or gradient vector even if the function is not differentiable at the point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fair point. It's sort of a technicality whether "there is no gradient" or "the gradient exists but most formulas using it require a differentiable function". I'll see if I can edit to be less strict about the exact definitions.

Comment: From what I have read in Apostol, differentiability of a scalar field is defined in terms of there existing a linear transformation that satisfies an equation that we call the first-order Taylor formula. This definition is made after a derivation that showed that it is possible for directional derivatives to exist in all directions at a point but the function is not continuous at that point (and also not differentiable).

Comment: When you say "this is not the definition of the gradient", what is the definition you are using then? In the book I am reading, that is indeed the definition of gradient of a scalar field.

Comment: @evianpring Some sources define the gradient from the partial derivatives and show that when differentiable, taking the dot product with the gradient gives that linear transformation. Others define the gradient from the linear transformation and show it can also be found from the partial derivatives. I've edited my answer to avoid exact definitions, so it doesn't matter which way you've started from. And the main point really is differentiability, not gradient.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\neq 0$ (not just $x$ and $y$ both positive or both negative),

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac12 \sgn(x)
 \sqrt{\left\lvert\frac yx\right\rvert}
$$
where $\sgn(x)$ is the "sign" function: $1$ if $x$ is positive, $-1$ if $x$ is negative, and $0$ if $x=0.$

But the right-hand side of that equation is undefined whenever $x = 0,$ not just at $(x,y)=(0,0).$
There is a good reason for that: for any fixed non-zero $y,$
$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ goes to $\infty$ as $x\to 0$ from above,
but it goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to 0$ from below.
The case $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only case where $x=0$ and it is possible to find a partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x.$
It should not really be surprising that the formula that doesn't work at any other point where $x=0$ also doesn't work at $(x,y)=(0,0).$

What is actually surprising (in a sense) is that $f(x,y)$ has both partial derivatives at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ despite the fact that the function is not differentiable there.
This has to do with the "folds" in the function along the $x$ and $y$ axes.
The fold along the $x$ axis, which prevents the existence of
$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ at any point on the $x$ axis except the origin,
nevertheless allows the existence of $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ along the $x$ axis.
At the same time, $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ does not exist at any point on the $y$ axis (other than the origin) due to the fold along the $y$ axis, but
$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ does exist along the $y$ axis.
Where the two axes cross, both partial derivatives are defined,
but the derivative is still not defined according to the usual definitions.

Comment: In your equation for the partial derivative what happens if $x$ is negative and $y$ is positive? Does the square root make sense?

Comment: Good catch, when I was modifying your formula to account for opposite signs I forgot about using absolute value inside the square root. It's fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

When we take the limit

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\tag{1}$$

what we find is that if $x$ and $y$ are positive then we have

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)y}-\sqrt{xy}}{h}\tag{2}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{y}{2\sqrt{(x+h)y}}\tag{3}$$

$$=\frac{y}{2\sqrt{xy}}\tag{4}$$

where we used L'Hopital's rule.

If $x=0$, however, we have

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,y)-f(0,y)}{h}\tag{5}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{hy}}{h}\tag{6}$$

which doesn't exist.

If we let $y=0$, however, then the limit becomes

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\tag{7}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{0}{h}\tag{8}$$

$$=0$$

The limits are in fact different limits because of the constraints on the values of $x$ and $y$.

Now, using the latter limit and the analogous one for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, we see that both partial derivatives exist at the origin.

According to Apostol, this means the gradient exists at the origin. It does not exist on the lines $x=0$ or $y=0$, because one of the partial derivatives doesn't exist on any point of these lines except the origin.

We can see these results intuitively from the 3d plot. The original question was more about the limits involved.

What about other directional derivatives at the origin?

Let $\vec{v}=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ be any vector. Then the directional derivative of $f$ with respect to $\vec{v}$ at the origin is

$$f'((0,0);\vec{v})=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec{0}+h\vec{v})-f(\vec{0})}{h}\tag{9}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(hv_1,hv_2)}{h}\tag{10}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{h^2v_1v_2}}{h}\tag{11}$$

$$=\sqrt{v_1v_2}\tag{12}$$

It appears all of them exist.

Is there a tangent plane at the origin, ie is the $f$ differentiable at the origin?

First of all, if $f$ were differentiable, then we would be able to write

$$f'((0,0);\vec{v})=\nabla f\cdot \vec{v}=\langle 0,0\rangle \cdot \langle v_1, v_2\rangle=0\tag{13}$$

which does not match (12).

I think we can conclude from this that $f$ isn't differentiable by a contrapositive.

However, there are other ways to reach this conclusion.

For example, consider the intersection of $f$ with plane $x=y$.

$$f(x,x)=\sqrt{|x^2|}=|x|\tag{14}$$

This curve isn't differentiable at the origin.

This means there is no tangent line at the origin in the direction of this curve, which there would have to be if there were a tangent plane there.